# Laravel, PDF generation when tried to generate the PDF with Marathi fonts format of fonts not proper

Tags: laravel, pdf, fonts, laravel-dompdf

I have tried to generate PDF in marathi fonts with Poppins-Regular fonts and its shows in marathi but format not proper.

When i copy the content from pdf and paste it in sublime or google search its shows correct.

Please find below the example PDF and the correct format

[image: PDF Generated content]

Original Content

```
    लॅटिन मूळ आणि मूर्खपणा सामग्री विपणन फायदा ग्राफिक डिझाइन__ लक्ष लक्ष केंद्रित करू शकता अशा प्रकारे मजकूर सामग्री  मन विचलित जात वाचक प्रतिबंधित करते आणि.
```